# How to insert short version of county names into a Geo Region Value Plot map

Tags: geography, geographics

I have the following counties in Florida :

```
counties = 
 Join @@ EntityValue[{Entity[
     "AdministrativeDivision", {"Florida", "UnitedStates"}]}, 
   EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Subdivisions"]]
```

I set my working directory as follows :

```
   setDir := 
 Quiet@Check[SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName, 
   SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]]
```

I have the following values :

```
   values = {21.2, 15.3, 14.9, 19.1, 12.4, 13.1, 21.1, 10.8, 
   14.4, 9.9, 11.7, 16.5, 26.1, 24.4, 15.1, 16.4, 12., 21.3,
    23.1, 16.1, 18.9, 21.6, 24., 23.3, 23.9, 14., 19.8, 
   15.5, 21.2, 10.6, 18., 17.7, 22.7, 12.6, 11.8, 18., 20.8,
    23., 28.3, 10.8, 16.2, 10.9, 16.7, 11.8, 9.1, 10.9, 
   21.8, 15.3, 14., 11.8, 13., 12.2, 16.1, 26.3, 10.2, 9.2, 
   11.2, 8.3, 12.8, 9.1, 20.3, 23.8, 22.2, 15.2, 12.9, 15.9,
    21.1};
```

I thread my counties and values as follows:

```
countyvalueassignment = Thread[counties -> values]
```

I define the following color function:

```
 getColor[val_] := 
 Which[8.3 <= val <= 11.7, Yellow, 11.7 < val <= 14, Orange, 
  14 < val <= 16.5, LightGreen, 16.5 < val <= 21.3, LightBlue, 
  21.3 < val <= 28.3, Blue]
```

and color assignment:

```
colorassignment = getColor[#] & /@ values
```

I thread the counties and their colors:

```
countycolorassignment = Thread[counties -> colorassignment]
```

and build the following map:

```
 flmap = GeoRegionValuePlot[countycolorassignment, 
  GeoBackground -> None, ImageSize -> 800]
```

Now I want to add the following shorter version of the county names.  For instance; instead of "Alachua County, Florida, United States" I want only "Alachua".  I also want to specify the location of the county - 
 name labels on the map as follows :

```
countynames = EntityValue[counties, "CanonicalName"];

loc = EntityValue[counties, "Position"];

countyshortnames = StringDrop[#, -6] & /@ countynames[[All, 1]];
```

Here is the second map:

```
MapOfFlorida = 
 GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], GeoStyling["OutlineMap"], 
   Polygon /@ counties, 
   Table[GeoMarker[loc[[j]], 
     Style[countyshortnames[[j]], TextAlignment -> Center, Black, 
      FontSize -> 10, Bold], "Scale" -> 1], {j, 1, 
     Length@countyshortnames}]}, GeoBackground -> None, 
  ImageSize -> 1200]
```

My question is : how can I insert the short version of the county names (as shown in the "MapOfFlorida" map) into the Geo Region Value plot "flmap"?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using all of the options available to you for [`GeoRegionValuePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoRegionValuePlot.html). All of what you are doing manually is already implemented in the options. Read the documentation of the function you are using for more features you are missing out on.

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[
 Thread[counties -> values],
 ColorFunction -> getColor,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 GeoLabels -> (GeoMarker[#3, 
     Style[StringDelete["County"]@*First@*CanonicalName@#2, 
      TextAlignment -> Center, Black, FontSize -> 9, Bold], 
     "Scale" -> 1] &),
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{{Yellow, Orange, LightGreen, LightBlue, Blue}, {8.3, 28.3}}, 
     {8.3, 11.7, 14, 16.5, 21.3, 28.3}],
 GeoBackground -> None,
 ImageSize -> 1200
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm curious about why some of the counties are depicted in gray (i.e.; Gadsden, Liberty, Madison, Hamilton, etc.) ?  It is not immediately obvious to me how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't received any responses (so far) I'm posting the following as a "final answer" even though I hope to get suggestions about how to improve this code from other Mathematica Stack Exchange participants.

```
counties = Join @@ EntityValue[{Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Florida", "UnitedStates"}]}, EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Subdivisions"]];

values = {21.2, 15.3, 14.9, 19.1, 12.4, 13.1, 21.1, 10.8, 14.4, 9.9, 
   11.7, 16.5, 26.1, 24.4, 15.1, 16.4, 12.0, 21.3, 23.1, 16.1, 18.9, 
   21.6, 24.0, 23.3, 23.9, 14.0, 19.8, 15.5, 21.2, 10.6, 18.0, 17.7, 
   22.7, 12.6, 11.8, 18.0, 20.8, 23.0, 28.3, 10.8, 16.2, 10.9, 16.7, 
   11.8, 9.1, 10.9, 21.8, 15.3, 14.0, 11.8, 13.0, 12.2, 16.1, 26.3, 
   10.2, 9.2, 11.2, 8.3, 12.8, 9.1, 20.3, 23.8, 22.2, 15.2, 12.9, 
   15.9, 21.1};

countyvalueassignment = Thread[counties -> values];

getColor[val_] := Which[8.3 <= val <= 11.7, Yellow, 11.7 < val <= 14, Orange, 14 < val <= 16.5, LightGreen, 16.5 < val <= 21.3, LightBlue, 21.3 < val <= 28.3, Magenta]

colorassignment = getColor[#] & /@ values

countycolorassignment = Thread[counties -> colorassignment];

flmap = GeoRegionValuePlot[countycolorassignment, GeoBackground -> Transparent, ImageSize -> 1500]

countynames = EntityValue[counties, "CanonicalName"];

countyshortnames = StringDrop[#, -6] & /@ countynames[[All, 1]];

loc = EntityValue[counties, "Position"];


MapOfFlorida = GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], GeoStyling[Transparent], Polygon /@ counties, Table[GeoMarker[loc[[j]], Rotate[Style[countyshortnames[[j]], TextAlignment -> Center, Black, FontSize -> 14, Bold], 90 Degree], "Scale" -> 1], {j, 1, Length@countyshortnames}]}, GeoBackground -> Transparent, ImageSize -> 1500]
```

Use ImageMultiply to "fuse" the  "flmap" and "MapOfFlorida" maps but, unfortunately notice that two of the county names are chopped; i.e.; Gadsden and Hamilton :

```
MapOfFloridaWithCountyNames = ImageMultiply[flmap, MapOfFlorida]
```

Build a legend:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

legendranges = Graphics[Legend[{{Framed[Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[{0, 0}]}]], Text[Style["8.3 - 11.7", Bold, 15]]}, {Framed[Graphics[{Orange, Rectangle[{0, 0}]}]], Text[Style["11.8 - 14.0", Bold, 15]]}, {Framed[Graphics[{LightGreen, Rectangle[{0, 0}]}]], Text[Style["14.1 - 16.5", Bold, 15]]}, {Framed[Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[{0, 0}]}]], Text[Style["16.6 - 21.3", Bold, 15]]}, {Framed[Graphics[{Magenta, Rectangle[{0, 0}]}]], Text[Style["21.4 - 28.3", Bold, 15]]}}, LegendLabel -> Text[Style["Legend", Bold, 18]]]]
```

Define your working directory:

```
setDir := Quiet@Check[SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName, SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]]

setDir
```

Export the above legend to your working directory to do some further editing to it:

```
Export["legendranges.png", legendranges]
```

Open "legendranges.png" in Paintbrush and do the necessary modifications using that software. The file with the modifications is called "desiredlegend.png" and
it is provided below:
[image: Modifications done using Paintbrush software:]

Now, import your file into your Mathematica platform:

```
desiredlegend = Import["desiredlegend.png"]
```

Use Show, Epilog and Inset to insert the desired legend into the map with county names:

```
MapOfFloridaWithCountyNamesAndLegend = Show[MapOfFloridaWithCountyNames, 
  Epilog -> Inset[desiredlegend, Center, {300, 260}, Scaled[0.5]]]
```

Export the final map to be used in your presentation:

```
Export["Florida_Map_with_County_Names_&_Legend(Page 20).png", MapOfFloridaWithCountyNamesAndLegend]
```

FINIS